# Fastify authentication with Keycloak using passport and openid-client

Tags: passport.js, keycloak, openid, session-storage, fastify

I am trying to protect REST API in Fastify. Firstly, I used fastify-keycloak-adapter, which I got successful with. But later I discovered, that Keycloak deprecated all their adapters and suggested using the OpenId solution.
I tried to use @fastify/passport, @fastify/session as session storage (later I would like to use Redis), and openid-client. But I am stuck on the server redirecting infinitely.

```
import KeycloakStrategy from '@exlinc/keycloak-passport';
import fastifyCookie from '@fastify/cookie';
import fastifyPassport from '@fastify/passport';
import fastifySecureSession from '@fastify/session';
import fastify from 'fastify';

const app = fastify({
  logger: {
    redact: ['req.headers.authorization'],
    level: 'debug',
    serializers: {
      req(request) {
        return {
          method: request.method,
          url: request.url,
          headers: request.headers,
          body: request.body
        };
      }
    }
  }
});

app.register(fastifyCookie);

app.register(fastifySecureSession, {
  secret: '0123456789012345678901234567890123',
  cookie: { secure: false },
  expires: 1800000,
  cookieName: 'sessionId'
});
app.register(fastifyPassport.initialize());
app.register(fastifyPassport.secureSession('session'));

fastifyPassport.registerUserSerializer(async (user, req) => {
  return user.keycloakId;
});

fastifyPassport.registerUserDeserializer(async (user, req) => {
  return user;
});


fastifyPassport.use(
  'keycloak',
  new KeycloakStrategy(
    {
      realm: 'myrealm',
      host: 'localhost',
      clientID: 'frontend',
      clientSecret: 'GIAhbWdKy7fZpfgfqWtifl734IHVCTCv',
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
      authorizationURL:
        'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
      tokenURL: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
      userInfoURL:
        'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
      cb(undefined, profile);
    }
  )
);

app.get('/', { preHandler: fastifyPassport.authenticate('keycloak') }, async (req, res) => {
  return `Hello world!`;
});

app.get('/callback', { preHandler: fastifyPassport.authenticate('keycloak') }, async (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get(
  '/login',
  fastifyPassport.authenticate('keycloak', {
    scope: ['profile']
  })
);

app.get('/logout', async (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  return { success: true };
});

app.listen({ port: 3000 }, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    app.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

What's wrong with my code? Or do you have another solution?